# Why i can not use "$" for call JQuery function in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

When i use JQuery like this it's not work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("abc");
});
```

But When i use JQuery like this it's work

```
JQuery(document).ready(function() {
    alert("abc");
});
```

How to config it's for use with "$"

Comment: there may be another library overriding jQuery or asp.net may be calling `jQuery.noConflict()`...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has to do with scoping. Basically, some other plugin or library you are using is already using  `$` to alias something other than jQuery.

To use jQuery as you are used to, like `$('#myInput').val();` you will need to place your code inside an `IIFE` - [Immediately Invoked Function Expression.](http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/) Inside that function, `$` will be locally scoped to refer to jQuery and will work as you expect

```
  // IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression
  (function($, window, document) {
      // The $ is now locally scoped

      // use $ normally inside here

  }(window.jQuery, window, document));
```

I have also read that you can use the below, but I have not tested it:

```
jQuery(function($){
// The $ is now locally scoped
// use $ normally
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the error once..I used this to resolve, may be due to different jQuery version.

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0):

please check in your code if some where you are using jQuery.noConflict(); The below link will give you more insight what it actually mean when it should be used [jquery.noconflict](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Answer (score 0):

try and use $j= jQuery.noConflict(); i think in you code some other java library is using the $ notation . once you declared it you can change the code as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("abc");
});
```

and this should solve your problem